# toggle class Does not work

Tags: javascript

I have some span like this:

```
<span class="read_more"> Read More </span>
```

and some div like this:

```
<div class="tab_inner">
    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

How can I toggle a class (`active`) for them

This is my code:

```
var showTab = document.getElementsByClassName("read_more");
var tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab_inner");

function showTabContent(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < showTab.length; i++) {
        showTab[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            tabContent.toggle('active');
        });
    }
}
```

And that I can't get DOM with `document.getElementsByClassName`
 or `document.getElementsByTagName` in a function. just `document.getElementById` working in function.

what should I do?

Comment: Do you want any *Read more* span to toggle all `tab_inner` spans? Or just  one (the one with the same index perhaps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only run toggle on a `classList` which is on a single element.  I have amended your code below

```js
var showTab = document.getElementsByClassName("read_more");
var tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab_inner");

function showTabContent() {
  for (var i = 0; i < showTab.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      showTab[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        tabContent[index].classList.toggle('active'); // I have assumed each read more has a corresponding tab content
      });
    })(i);
  }
}

showTabContent();
```

```css
.tab_inner.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="read_more">read more</div>
<div class="tab_inner">tab content</div>
<div class="read_more">read more</div>
<div class="tab_inner">tab content</div>
```

Comment: Pete: Entering the `i` wouldn't work and throws undefined, as the anonymous function cannot find `i` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method  `toggle()` of the [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), that is a read-only property which returns a live `DOMTokenList` collection of the class attributes of the element.

Code:

```js
var showTab = document.getElementsByClassName('read_more'),
    tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName('tab_inner');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(showTab, function(elem, index) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    tabContent[index].classList.toggle('active'); 
  });
});
```

```css
.read_more {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab_inner.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="read_more">Read More</span>
<div class="tab_inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, dignissimos.</p>
</div>

<span class="read_more">Read More</span>
<div class="tab_inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quam dolor quae error eligendi numquam ipsum. Assumenda modi, explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

Note also that you can iterate over the array-like [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) by calling Array's `forEach()` method.